# New printer HP 5540 envy he scanner doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, scanner

Sorry,
I've got the 14.04 version.

Comment: @andrea - when did you buy your printer ? and I try to answer this with my little contribution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mattering if you use 14.04 Ubuntu or 15.04 Ubuntu or if this would concern 16.04 Ubuntu.

Open terminal and check if hplip is already installed. But first you need to switch on your brandish new printer. Plug-in the usb-cable into your Ubuntu-machine. Then reboot your Ubuntu-machine. When logged in after re-boot then open a terminal and type in (connected to internet):

> sudo apt-get install hplip

Your machine is probably reporting that hplip is already installed.
So we do then :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall hplip

Machine is probably reporting that hplip is already installed but therefore we did reinstallation.

Then you can run in terminal :

> sudo hp-setup -i

Your printer should be recognized and set-up when you have followed the steps of hp-setup. Simply then print test-page and all should be fine now.